# count if field in another list SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint

I have 2 SharePoint lists like below
I want to make a column in list B to count if this item listed or not in specific column in list A

```
list A
items
item1
item4
item6

list B
items   Count in list A
item1   1
item2   0
item3   0
item4   1
item5   0
item6   1
item7   0
item8   0
```

How to do this ??

Answer (score 0):

You could create a LOOK UP column in list B,and get information from list A,there is a count attribute of look up column that can be used.
Complete example for your reference：
https://wonderlaura.com/2013/08/06/sharepoint-column-count-related-items/
Updated:
[image]

[image]

Comment: You only need to apply the method in the example to your list.

Comment: that's can't applied on my example
list A don't get data from list B
in my example
the data in list A may not listed in list B
so i want to link List B to List A but I can't link list A to B
I need something like countif in Excel
if result will be 1 if not listed result will be 0

Comment: OK,Then there is no direct way to get this value. You need to modify the view in list A to group and count the corresponding columns, and then use code to read these values and set them to list B.

Comment: Check this Sheet https://www.dropbox.com/s/ss6cnvknqhjqsiq/Book1.xlsx?dl=0

Comment: thanks for your support. List A and List B have unique items so group will not help me. let me explain to you. lest B the customers that we sent them a letter to buy our product. list A is all sold items that we send letters to them or without letter. so may i sent cst a letter but he didn't buy yet. all i want to do is add a column in list B IS CST bought ornot. so if he listed in List A will get 1 if not will get 0. i can easily export list A and B to excel and get data i want with countif then update list B with edit mode. but if there a way to update list B automatically that will be great

Comment: any reply please